# Finding $d=\gcd(a,b)$; finding integers $m$ and $n$: $d=ma+nb$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Let $a=8316$ and $b=10920$

a) Find $d=\gcd(a,b)$. greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$

b) Find integers $m$ and $n$ such that $d=ma+nb$

this is what i've tried so far. correct me if I'm wrong

8316= 8016*4 + 300

10920= 10800*300 + 120

300= 120*2 + 60

60=30*2

Comment: what have u tried?

Comment: euclidian algorithm. But I can't seem to get it right

Comment: Oh, blame my teacher then. That's how he put it. Such prejudice :) If I knew a lot about the topic I wouldn't have asked, you know? I thought people ask questions here to be answered not be treated with sarcasm

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Usually questions receive a much better and more helpful response if you include your own thoughts and efforts, explaining what you've tried and what you're having trouble with.

Comment: We are not to blame ur teacher. There are clear rules on how to use the site and people of every level are welcome here. Though, its **your** responsibility to put a question up to quality and make it explicit what is that you have tried and where you think you have failed or got stuck. If you would have shown any attempt it would have been clear what level you were at and what might type of help you needed. If a comment suggests that you might not even known what the euclidean algorithm is then your questions needs some work. There are tutorials here on how to make good questions. ;)

Answer (score 2):

a) I solved the $gcd$ is by using Euclidian algorithm, where the $gcd(a,b)$ is defined as 
\begin{align}
a &= q_1b + r_1 \\
b &= q_2r_1 + r_2 \\
r_1 &= q_3r_2 + r_3 \\
\end{align} and so on. Start by calculating $\frac{a}{b}$. You should notice that it will be a decimal number. Take how many times $b$ goes into $a$ (should be the integer part of your number, i.e 2.967 would be 2) and let that be your $q_1$. Your $r_1$ is defined as $a - q_1b$. Now your second line will begin with $b$ and keep iterating this process to create 
\begin{align}
10920 &= (1)8316 + 2604 \\
8316 &= (3)2604 + 504 \\
2604 &= (5)504 + 84 \\
504 &= (6)84 + 0.
\end{align} Once zero is the last number to be added, the procedure stops, and we use (in this case) 84 as the $gcd$.

b) Using the information we were given above, work backward! Start with the $gcd$, in this case, 84. From the third line, we know that 
\begin{align}
84 &= 2604 - (5)504 .
\end{align} Now looking at line two, we can see that 
\begin{align}
504 &= 8316 -(3)2604,
\end{align} so changing the 504 in the equation above leaves
\begin{align}
84 &= 2604 - (5)(8316 - (3)2604) \\
84 &= (16)2604 - (5)8316.
\end{align} Continue repeating this process and it will leave create..
\begin{align}
84 &= 16((1)10920 - (1)8316) - (5)8316 \\
84 &= (16)10920 - (21)8316.
\end{align} Notice that we have our $a$ and $b$ that we started with, along with constants in front of them? Those two constants, 16 and $-21$ are your answers!!
In the future, anytime you see a question where it asks to find integers $m$ and $n$ and you have no idea what to do, your best bet is to always try to tackle it like this!

Answer (score 1):

The *Extended Euclidean algorithm* yields the coefficients *and* the g.c.d.:

[image]

Hence  the g.c.d. is $84$, and 
$$84=-21\cdot 8316+16\cdot 10920$$